# Who was the little girl being possessed by Orochimaru during his fight with 3rd Hokage?

Tags: naruto

I am wondering, during Orochimaru's fight with the 3rd Hokage, there's a little girl whom Orochimaru possessed.

Who was that girl? What is her ability, or why did Orochimaru choose to possess her?

I tried browsing the net and replaying the sequel but still can't find that little girl in the story.

Comment: Konoha Crush Arc: volumes 13-16, chapters 116 to 138 of the manga and episodes 68 to 80 of Naruto (anime)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about the girl Orochimaru "became" during the fight with the 3rd Hokage on the roof during the Chunin exams (Ch. 121). I just went back and read that part of the story and I don't believe her identity was ever stated. This is the episode in the anime where he rips his face off and reveals this girl's face:

[image]

In other words this is the girl he used as his vessel.

Comment: but who is she? Why the 3rd Hohage got mad when he saw her?

Comment: @jcho360 We don't know, but give how the 3rd cared for the children of the village, it wouldn't be a stretch to see him get angry at harm coming to any child, regardless of who it was.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have much canon information to go on, other than the fact that she was probably powerful, since Orochimaru possessed her body.

Note that the Naruto wikia folks couldn't dig up much about her either, and as a result, the wikia page for her ended up being deleted due to lack of notability. (See the [discussion for that page](https://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Orochimaru%27s_Previous_Body).)